# traversing the xaml document programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I have the following xaml:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="MESSAGES" x:Name="Messages">
    ...
    <ListBox x:Name="MessagesStreamList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="ParticipantImages">
                </Grid>
```

How do I traverse programmatically to get a hold of `ParticipantImages` so I can programmatically add columns etc?

I do not have direct access to `ParticipantImages`

**---------EDIT-----------**

I just tried using the VisualTreeHelper:

```
int poop = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MessagesStreamList);
```

but this returns a count of **0**.

Is this something to do with the ItemTemplate again?

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? Why don't you have direct access to that `Grid`?

Comment: WPF is designed to work well with binding when you follow the Model View ViewModel pattern.  The way that you are trying to do this will force you to do extra work.  Could you please expand on what you are trying to do so that we can give you a better answer?

Comment: I want to do a collage of images so I want to add rows and columns programmatically based on bound data (the images that will fill the rows and columns)

Comment: have you tried `VisualTreeHelper`? if not then I think this is what you are looking for. more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Damn, I have a lot to traverse... Do you know a nice little helper function to traverse (a bit like jquery selector to be honest)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is in a DataTemplate you cannot get it by name from within the ListBox (or window containing the listbox).

What you can do, is replace the Grid that is inside the data template with a user-control, put the grid into that user control, and then use code inside that user control to get to the Grid.

The user control would be defined as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded_1">
<Grid x:Name="ParticipantImages">

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And then in code you could do:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParticipantImages.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: "use code insde that user control" - could I have an example :) ?

Comment: It kind of depends on when you are trying to do your manipulation of ParticipantImages. I'll edit to demonstrate if you are trying to do it as the control is loaded.

Comment: Argh, I'm totally new to this whole thing so I guess it's going to take my a long time to understand this, but basically.. I run initializecomponents in my .cs file, and straight after I set a property of a view model to what I hope to be the ParticipantImages Grid. this is so in my viewmodel I can modify columns etc on the fly.

Comment: It sounds like you could probably do that with a binding, but I updated anyhow... :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a delayed response, but I came across this today when looking for something similar.

My goal was to modify some item's properties within a DataTemplate list box.
Here is my structure:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="Items_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
```

On selection change, I wanted to modify some properties of the item that was changed. I don't imagine this is the most efficient way but it's what I got.

```
private void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)sender;

        obj = loopUntilDesiredTypeIsFound<ListBoxItem>(obj);

        for (int i=0; i<VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj,i);
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
                DependencyObject container = loopUntilDesiredTypeIsFound<Grid>(item);
//here we will have the Grid container for the display objects, such as textblocks, checkboxes, etc..
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private DependencyObject getChild(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) > 0 )
        {
            return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, 0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DependencyObject loopUntilDesiredTypeIsFound<T>(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        while (obj != null)
        {
            int children = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
            if (getChild(obj) is T)
            {
                return obj;
            }
            obj = getChild(obj);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Oh cool man, I will try to read through this later on. Thanks for the time brah